# In perl, access one of the multiple lines which stored in single array element

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I have this sample text which I would like to access one of the multiple lines from a single array element.

```
Student 1:
Math 83
Chemistry 60
Physics 75

Student 2:
Math 69
Chemistry 76
Physics 73
Art A-
```

My script for storing multiple lines to a single array element is as following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'Text1' or die "Could not open file to read:$!";
my $file = do { local $/; <$fh> };
my @a = split /\n\n/, $file;
close $fh;

print "First array element is $a[0]\n";
print "Second array element is $a[1]\n";
```

The output is

```
First array element is Student 1:
Math 83
Chemistry 60
Physics 75
Second array element is Student 2:
Math 69
Chemistry 76
Physics 73
Art A-
```

Is there a better way for me to access and grab one of the multiple lines in first or 2nd element of the array for further usage? i.e, I need `Math score` from each student.
Here is what I come up so far, to join the first element of the array and split them again. Thanks in advance.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'Text1' or die "Could not open file to read:$!";
my $file = do { local $/; <$fh> };
my @a = split /\n\n/, $file;
close $fh;

print "First array element is $a[0]\n";
print "Second array element is $a[1]\n";

my $str=join('',$a[0]);
my @score1 = split('\n',$str);
$str=join('',$a[1]);
my @score2 = split('\n',$str);

print "Student 1 : $score1[1]\n";
print "Student 2 : $score2[1]\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your read and split can be simplified to using readline's paragraph mode:

```
my @student = do { local $/ = ""; <$fh> };
```

I would be inclined to break each student up into a hash:

```
my @student = map {
    my ($student, $scores) = /\A(.*):\n(.*)/s;
    {
        'Name' => $student,
        split ' ', $scores
    }
} do { local $/ = ""; <$fh> };

for my $student_number (0..1) {
    print "Name: $student[$student_number]{Name}  Math Score: $student[$student_number]{Math}\n";
}
```

If there is no blank line between students:

```
my @student;
my $current_student;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    if ( my ($name) = $line =~ /^(.*):/ ) {
        $current_student = { 'Name' => $name };
        $line =~ s/^.*://;
        push @student, $current_student;
    }
    my @scores = split ' ', $line;
    while ( my ($subject, $score) = splice(@scores, 0, 2) ) {
        $current_student->{$subject} = $score;
    }
}
```

(A subject has to be on the same line as its score.)

Comment: Thanks! This is a neat output for display. Would you allow me for another question? What if there is no newline between the two student's data? How can I split the data?

Comment: how would you tell when a new student starts?  the colon?

Comment: Is it possible? for colon?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of 'slurping' the entire file, you could read in one 'paragraph' at a time by setting `$/` to `""`. I would have used a hash instead of `@score1` and `@score2`. Then you could address the sought math score by using Math as a key. It would look something like this-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @grades;

{
    local $/ = "";
    while (<DATA>) {
        push @grades, { split };
    }   
}

for my $href (@grades) {
    print "student: $href->{Student} Math: $href->{Math}\n";    
}
```

Output-

```
student: 1: Math: 83
student: 2: Math: 69
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. Another question if you allow me, what if there is no newline between the two student's data? `Student 1:
Math 83
Chemistry 60
Physics 75
Student 2:
Math 69
Chemistry 76
Physics 73
Art A-` How would I have split it? I do not wish to use splice operator since the subjects might be different for each student.